# Normalizing matrix values python/R

Tags: r, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, python

I am trying to fill missing values in `1000 x 1000` matrices. Dataset1 contains such `1000 x 1000` matrice with value ranging 1-100. Any point which has value 0, that means it is missing.

Sample dataset: [Link](https://gist.github.com/karimkhanp/2216bf373d9fbc9137b4)

Dataset2 is historical data to get missing values. It has 4k rows with 2 column. column1 contains any values among 1-100 and column 2 corresponding state value ranging from 1-4.

It looks like this: [Link](https://gist.github.com/karimkhanp/1692f1f76718c35e939f)

**My approach to get the missing value:**

1. Get average state value for each 1-100 value in ds2
2. replace each values 1-100 in ds1 with is mapping values in ds2
3. to get missing value, get average of all neighbour for each point having values 0

Is it correct for missnig value retrival?

In python or R, is there any helping package for this stuff? doing mauanlly I could have done, but willing to know if any supportive function are there

Comment: Are you interested in statistical techniques for the imputation of missing data *per se*, or just coding issues?

Comment: @chl: I would be happy to see statistical techniques too for the same

Comment: I think the question has some statistical content, though as I type this the answers don't seem to .

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate how `fillna` can achieve what you want, I have an attempt as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# supposed the ds1 is your dataset1, here with 0..1000 as column, 0..100 as index
ds1 = pd.read_table('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/karimkhanp/2216bf373d9fbc9137b4/raw/dead5296ea0d69c85e3d3784a0317383c3c21fce/ds1', sep=' ', header=None)

ds1.head()
Out[23]: 
   0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     ...   991   0    13    15    15   NaN   NaN   NaN    14   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...    NaN   
1    14    13    14    14    16   NaN   NaN   NaN    16   NaN  ...    NaN   
2    16   NaN    13    14   NaN    14    14   NaN    16   NaN  ...     16   
3    16   NaN    15    16    14    15    15   NaN   NaN    13  ...    NaN   
4   NaN    13    13    16    15   NaN    15   NaN    15   NaN  ...     16   

   992   993   994   995   996   997   998   999   1000  
0    14    14    13    13   NaN    15    15    16   NaN  
1    16   NaN    16    16    15    13   NaN    16   NaN  
2    14    14   NaN    15    14   NaN    15   NaN   NaN  
3    13    15    14    16    16    13    16    14   NaN  
4    15    15    14    14    14   NaN    14   NaN   NaN  

[5 rows x 1001 columns]

# and ds2 is your dataset2, [0, 1] as columns etc.
ds2 = pd.read_table('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/karimkhanp/1692f1f76718c35e939f/raw/6f6b348ab0879b702e1c3c5e362e9d2062e9e9bc/ds2', header=None, sep=' ')

ds2.head()
Out[24]: 
    0  1
0  11  1
1  19  1
2  42  2
3  16  1
4  63  3
```

---

```
# first get the mean of what first-column values of ds2
ds2_mean = ds2.groupby(0).mean()

ds2_mean.head()
Out[26]: 
           1
0           
10  1.103774
11  1.173554
12  1.168224
13  1.312500
14  1.133333

# replace all 0's in ds1 to nan
ds1.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)

# then apply the fillna on a per row basis and replace with relative ds2_mean[1]
# values according to x-index on ds1
ds1 = ds1.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(ds2_mean[1]))
```

It should achieve what you want. I am way past my sleeping time so there may be mistakes, please let me know in that case and I will correct it when I wake up, hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and efforts. Could you please explain last line `ds1 = ds1.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(ds2_mean[1]))`

Comment: @user2129623, not a problem. `ds1.apply(...)` means apply a function to the whole ds1, whereas `lambda x: x.fillna(...)` means on each row to apply the `fillna` <-- think of lambda as each row in this case. Finally, fill na with values from `ds2_mean[1]`, `[1]` is the column header which `ds2_mean[1]` yields the values list with indexes/value pairs (think of Series with indexes), that is, fill the na with relative indexed value from `ds2_mean`. Does it all make sense now?

Comment: thanks a lot, but I want little different. I dont want to replace with index value. also not the NA value. I want value in col1 of ds2 should be replace by corresponding col2 value in ds1

Answer (score 0):

try `fillna` and `dropna` functions in pandas

Comment: @cdaladenes: thanks a lot, but does approach i have used for missing value is reasonable?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer?